# Can't call method from class 1 in class 2

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

I have 2 classes. 1 class looks like this and has the "work" method.

```
public class Worker extends Employee
{
    int hourPay;
    int amountHours = 0;

    public Worker(String name, int hourPay)
    {
        super(name);
        this.hourPay = hourPay;
    }

public void work(int hours)
    {
        amountHours = amountHours + hours;
    }

    ...
}
```

I'm trying to call this class in the constructor of another class like this:

```
   public Employees()
   {
      john = new Clerk("Jan", 1750); 
      pete = new Worker("Piet", 9); // Clerk and Worker are classes inherited from Employees
      pete.work(5);

      members[0] = john;
      members[1] = pete;
   }
```

Why doesn't this work? I always receive the error "cannot find symbol - method work(int)"

Comment: Can you provide the declaration of your class Worker ?

Comment: are you getting a `DoesNotWorkException`?

Comment: Show more code, show the **complete** error message.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but the variable uren is not used in your work method.

Comment: That is the complete error message

Comment: In a comment of your code you have said that `Clerk and Worker are classes inherited from Employees`: so is it `Employee` or `Employees` ?

Comment: Show where you declare pete.  Not just where you initialize it.

Comment: @TrickBoss, This should not be too hard to copy source code from your favorite IDE and paste it here. Your complete question has case problem, it might even have super-sub class relation issue. But the way  you pasted your code in your question isn't making a clear sense. Rather a complete misleading

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because despite our requests for further relevant information and clarification, the original poster is withholding it from us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the variable `pete` is declared as class `Employee`, which means that only methods of that class can be called on that variable. You must either declare `pete` as type `Worker`, or use a cast:

```
((Worker)pete).work(5);
```

Comment: That's exactly what was wrong, thanks a lot!

Comment: @TrickBoss You should accept his answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: What he saying is that pete is declared like this. Employee pete; and NOT Worker pete; hence the need to cast it to a Worker.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `Worker` class does not compile. In your `Worker` class you have a case problem. Your constructor is with a small `w` where it should be a capital `W`

Comment: sorry, I translated it from the original language (Dutch) and made an error typing it here, though it's correct in my program

Answer (score 0):

This is not a constructor:

```
public worker(String name, int hourPay)
{
    super(name);
    this.hourPay = hourPay;
}
```

It should be:

```
public Worker(String name, int hourPay) // note the capital W
{
    super(name);
    this.hourPay = hourPay;
}
```

Besides, the message "cannot find symbol" is usually caused by a missing import (at least it looks like this is the case in your code). Check your imports.

Comment: @Whomever downvoted: care to explain?

Comment: the error he is having `cannot find symbol - method work(int)`; not with `Worker(name, hourplay)`, btw i am not the downvoter

Comment: I guess you didn't read my whole answer. (Hint: last 2 lines).

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialised anything properly. What type is `members[]`? Assuming `pete` is an object of Workers, you need to initialise it as `Workers pete = new Worker("Piet", 9)` and so forth.

Answer (score -2):

you are calling a subclass constructor in the baseclass constuctor. the subsclass object is not created until and unless the baseclass constructor has finished, right, so therefore, when the baseclass constructor is finishing it get's the subclass object is not created and therefore, the work method is not into existence and hence the error.

Comment: This is yet to confirm, `Employee` and `Employees` are not same